# Late 90s scifi movie where aliens blow up earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely recall seeing a movie trailer, most likely in the late 90s or early 2000s, about a movie set in the year 3000 where aliens blow up Earth. Anyone know what it might have been?

Edit: This was in English, in an American movie theater. I recall the trailer being live action, though it's possible my memory is faulty.

Comment: What kind of movie was it? Live action? Animation? Where did you see it? USA? Europe? Asia? What language was it in? By the way, welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: Do you mean they *literally* [blew up the entire planet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrVmNg7i9e4) or just [nuked us from orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKDXaX07APM)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the trailer for Titan A.E., released in 2000.

It's prominently mentioned that the setting is the year **3028**, right before the Earth gets pulverised

Comment: It doesn't seem similar to what I remember, but it's possible. I'll see if anyone comes up with a different suggestion. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Antimony - The Earth blows up at 0:30

Comment: @Antimony - If there are any other details you can recall, you should add those into the original post.

Comment: Sorry I never got around to accepting this answer before. I think this must have been what I remember, and the rest is my memory playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 3):

It's not set in the year 3000, but aliens blow up Earth in the trailer to Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy, which was released in 2005.