# Looking for movie where aliens destroy Earth, with spike like bombs, drilling into the crust

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm looking for an old movie where aliens fire missiles into the Earth's crust and blow it inside out. The bombs were like spikes that drilled into the Earth's crust before exploding.

Watched it when I was a little kid. It was about 15 to 20 years ago.

Comment: That seems a bit sparse. Aliens are always blowing up the Earth. So much so that you'd think that had little better to do...

Comment: What did the aliens look like? Why were they blowing up the earth? When were you a little kid? Was there any other plot? Did someone try to stop them? What were the aliens called? What did their missiles look like? What was the budget on this film? Was it in black and white or colour?

Comment: When were you a little kid? If you're 120 years old now, it makes a difference.

Comment: How old is "old"?

Comment: It was about 15 to 20 years ago. The bombs were like spikes that drilled into the Earth's crust before exploding.

Comment: Was it a film or a TV series. This sounds like the end of Babylon 5

Comment: One possibility is Don Bluth's animated movie Titan A.E. from 2000. it opens with aliens destroying the Earth, though with an energy weapon rather than missile. The opening scene (where the Earth is destroyed) can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQO8MTlO69U

Comment: Was it animated?

Comment: Is there anything more you can remember? It sounds similar to a question accessible from the link below: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145509/late-90s-scifi-movie-where-aliens-blow-up-earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't an animated movie, a possibility within the timeframe given by OP,  is Babylon 5: A Call to Arms (1999).

The missiles description fits well with the mode of operation of the [Shadow Planet Killer](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Cloud). However, the destroyed planet wasn't Earth, but Daltron VII.

Comment: I do believe that it's the one, thanks.